# using 'and' and 'or' statement combined in 'if statement' in bash using awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to combine `&&` and `||` in 'if statement' in awk. This is what basically I am doing:

```
awk '{if( ($3=="/M" && $4>=35) || ($3 =="/M" && $5 = "/Married" && $4 >= 25) || ($3 == "/F" && $4 = 36) )} {print}'
```

My statement is not working as expected. Instead, it is returning an error. Is there a syntax error in this question or is it needs to be rephrased? Please help.

This is what the file looks like:

```
Kamila Haynes F 52 Single 2015 604-555-8291 76102
Aliana Hardin F 45 Single 2016 236-555-5788 66456
Charlee Ortega F 24 Single 2016 604-555-8187 85009
Ryan Nelson M 25 Married 2017 604-555-2323 44715   
Ruth Contreras F 49 Single 2016 604-555-8829 64391    
Adrienne Gould F 23 Single 2017 604-555-7973 72203    
Kayson Blair M 40 Married 2016 778-555-6806 69082    
Alexia Hardy F 40 Married 2015 778-555-6684 72270    
Lochlan Bradshaw M 27 Single 2016 236-555-7631 66518    
Mohammed Allison M 27 Single 2016 778-555-4204 70087
```

this is what the desired output needs to be:

All the men 35 years old or older, and all of the married men 25 years old or older needs to be deleted. Also, all of the women which are not exactly 36 years old are also required to be deleted. Output may not be there (the "next" command may be of use here).

EDIT:
This is what the output may look like:

`Kamila Haynes F 52 Single 2015 604-555-8291 76102
Aliana Hardin F 45 Single 2016 236-555-5788 66456
Charlee Ortega F 24 Single 2016 604-555-8187 85009
Ruth Contreras F 49 Single 2016 604-555-8829 64391
Adrienne Gould F 23 Single 2017 604-555-7973 72203
Alexia Hardy F 40 Married 2015 778-555-6684 72270
Lochlan Bradshaw M 27 Single 2016 236-555-7631 66518
Mohammed Allison M 27 Single 2016 778-555-4204 70087`

Comment: `$5 = "/Married"` isn't a comparison; neither is `$4 = 36`. These are assignments which, if evaluated, alter the values of the `$5` and `$4` fields.

Comment: This is what the output should be: ( I could not paste this line by line ) Kamila Haynes F 52 Single 2015 604-555-8291 76102 ;;

Aliana Hardin F 45 Single 2016 236-555-5788 66456 ;;

Charlee Ortega F 24 Single 2016 604-555-8187 85009 ;;

Ruth Contreras F 49 Single 2016 604-555-8829 64391 ;;

Adrienne Gould F 23 Single 2017 604-555-7973 72203 ;;

Alexia Hardy F 40 Married 2015 778-555-6684 72270 ;;

Lochlan Bradshaw M 27 Single 2016 236-555-7631 66518 ;;

Mohammed Allison M 27 Single 2016 778-555-4204 70087

Comment: Paste it in your original post https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48799038/edit

Comment: @GaganpreetSinghMaan, Gagan, please use button `{}` for adding your sample inputs/outputs in CODE TAGS.

Comment: BTW, this is purely an awk question -- bash syntax has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Yes sir. I realised this later on how to shortlist my questions using proper tags and comments. Thanks for helping me out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you:

```
awk '!($3=="M" && $4>=35) && !($3=="F" && $4>=25) && !($3=="F" && $4!=36)'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

`!($3=="M" && $4>=35)`: This condition will check if 3rd field(which is I believe always GENDER field) is `M` and 4 field(which is I believe always AGE field) so checking here if 3rd field is M and 4th field is greater than or equal to 35 `!` in starting of it will Negate the condition(to make it opposite the condition), so it will remove all those lines which Males are having greater Age than 35.

`&&`: AND between 2 conditions means both should conditions should be TRUE.

`!($3=="F" && $4>=25)`: Checking here if a person with Gender of female and age is more than 25 should NOT be printed.

`&& !($3=="F" && $4!=36)'`: && makes sure all conditions should be TRUE and condition I am putting is if line is having a female value on 3rd field and its 4th field is not equal to 36 then skip that line.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! That worked for me very well.

Comment: No need to quote integers

Comment: @GaganpreetSinghMaan, also add `$5=="Married" too in above 2nd condition `$3=="F" && $4>="25" && $5=="Married"` to get it, let me know how it goes then.